# Is this is the right way to do these one-to-one functions, finding their inverse, if not, how to do it?

Tags: functions

Question 1) 
  $f(x) = 1-x$

My answer (1):   $f(x) = 1-x$, $y = 1 - x$, $y + 1 = x$, $x = y + 1$,  $f$ of inverse $f(y) = y + 1$

---

Question 2) :  $f(x) = \dfrac{2x}{x-1}$

My answer 2) :  $f(x) = \frac{2x}{x-1} = y$, $\frac{2x}{x-1}$,  $y+1=2x$, $\frac{y+1}{2} = x$, $x= \frac{y+1}{2}$, $f$ of inverse $f(y) = \frac{y+1}{2}$

---

Question 3):  $f(x) = \sqrt{5} - x$

My answer 3) : $f(x) = \sqrt{5} - x = y = \sqrt{5} - x = y + 5 = x = x = y + 5$, f of inverse $f(y) = y + 5$

---

Question 4):  $f(x) = x^3$

My answer 4): $f(x) = x^3$,  $y=x^3$, $y^3 = x$, $x=y^3$, f of inverse $f(y)  = y^3$

Comment: Question 2: do you mean $\frac{2x}{x-1}$? Question 3: do you mean $\sqrt{5}-x$?

Comment: yes, that's how I meant for both of them

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, I suggest you lay out your work vertically.  If you read your answer to 3), you will notice that you obtained $y = y + 5$.

Comment: hmm, sorry for my mistakes and thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1.** I believe the method is right, but there is a small mistake.

\begin{align*}
y &= 1-x \\
y-1 &= -x \\
1-y &= x
\end{align*}

---

**Question 2.**

\begin{align*}
y &= \frac{2x}{x+1} \\
\frac{y}{2} &= \frac{x}{x+1} \\
\frac{y}{2} &= 1-\frac{1}{x+1} \\
\frac{y}{2}-1 &= -\frac{1}{x+1} \\
1-\frac{y}{2} &= \frac{1}{x+1} \\
\frac{1}{1-\frac{y}{2}} &= x+1 \\
\frac{1}{1-\frac{y}{2}}-1 &= x \\
\end{align*}

---

**Question 3.**
This is similiar to question 1, can you do this yourself?

\begin{align*}
y &= \sqrt{5}-x \\
y-\sqrt{5} &= -x \\
\sqrt{5}-y &= x
\end{align*}

---

**Question 4.**

\begin{align*}
y &= x^3 \\
\sqrt[3]{y} &= x
\end{align*}

Comment: hmmm, thanks, how about  number 2 and 3?

Comment: @HeeganHero See my comment under your question.

Comment: I have done 2 since that one is quite hard.

Comment: yes, I can do number 3, thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, if you like the answer, you can also upvote it, in addition to accepting it.

Comment: ;( VoteUp requires 15 reputation, getting that error,  but I'll do it after reaching that point :)

Comment: @ wythagoras , I tried number 3, is this right please ,f(x) =  √5−x , y = √5−x = -x , 5-y = x , x= 5-y

Comment: Sorry, I always forget about the reputation thresholds. Regarding question 3,  why is the root suddenly gone?

Comment: Can you do f(x)=3-x?

Comment: hhh you're right, I supposed not to take that shortcut, on the other way, F(x)=3-x, y=3-x=-x , 3-y=x, x=3-y

Comment: You found the correct function, but please, do not write y=3-x=-x, because that implies 3-x=-x, which is not true.

Comment: hmmm, now I know that, you are very helpful, thanks indeed.